# Convert MS word margins into geometry package margins

Tags: margins, conversion, geometry, msword

I would like to convert the following margins that I have found in my MS word document to geometry package.

> Top: 2.38cm Bottom: 2.38cm Inside: 2.29cm Outside: 1.52cm
>
> Gutter: 0cm

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{
    paperheight=8.00in,
    top=2.38cm,
    bottom=2.38cm, 
    paperwidth=5.25in,
    inner=2.29cm,
    outer=1.52cm,
    %bindingoffset=.75in,
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The main issue here is that createspace is complaining that the gutter is insufficient and should be atleast `.75"`. The margins that I have provided are from their word template but when I submit it for review I get an insufficient gutter margin error that states I need gutter margin of atleast `.75in` and inside, top, bottom, outer, margins of atleast `.25in`. Does my code follow those specifications?

EDIT:

Here is an image from createspace's interior file reviewer. You can see that the page is coming out the dotted lines. On the left you can see the errors that have shown up. This image includes the answer that was suggested by @DL6ER [image].

EDIT 2:

I already have had my book approved for a book proof and have already recevied the proof. The only reason, I want to change the margins is because the margins I used to get the book approved were odd. The text was *too* close to the gutter. Here is the code that I used, maybe, someone can manipulate it so the text isn't so close to the gutter and the outside margin isn't so large.

```
\geometry{ paperheight=8.00in, top=.75in, bottom=.75in, paperwidth=5.25in, inner=.38in, outer=.75in, bindingoffset=.75in, }
```

Here is image of it on createspace. Aside from the showframe, the dimensions are fine (according to createspace). The main issue that I am having is that outside margin (the one indicated by the arrow) is too *in* so if that could be stretched then that would be perfect or even if the entire text could be centred then that would be fine also.

[image]

EDIT 3:

I have contacted Createspace and they have informed that only the first 18 pages of my document are a little bit outside of the required amount, the rest of the book is perfect. I have reviewed the other pages as well and that seems to be exactly the case. My `Introduction` is the only portion of the book that is outside the margins, otherwise, the rest of the book is fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: I do not really understand why they complain about the gutter margin, when there is no in the word document. Are you sure you got the right margins from word? All your other margins are greater than .25"...

Comment: @DL6ER Yup, I got the margins right from word.

Comment: Your geometry settings comply with the specs you've posted at the top of your question. Can you post the exact error message you get from createspace? A wild guess: createspace may not appreciate overfull boxes. I noticed you get some overfull boxes in your document; for instance, on page 2, "Morbi" sticks out in the right margin (this is obvious if you load the `showframe` option of the geometry package). Increasing `\tolerance` a bit will help getting rid of overfull boxes and might resolve the problem.

Comment: @Jubobs I have included an image that shows the errors by createspace's interior reviewer and you are correct about overfull boxes. I have one overfull vbox with following error `Overfull \vbox (13.59999pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
[7] [8`.

Comment: @gekkostate: Ok, thanks for the picture, but I have to admit that I don't understand what they are doing there, because (to me) it seems like they use the same page for the left and the right side (see the line on the right side of the textarea which indicates a right side, the line on the left of the textarea indicationg a left side). I my eyes everything is setup just fine and the check of which you posted the screenshot is judging wrong! They are using the "right-side" margins on the right side (no warnings here), but also on the left side - of course there the margins are wrong!

Comment: @DL6ER Oh, I see what you are saying. How can I can change that so it works out?

Comment: Following DL6ER's comment, perhaps you should try submitting a file produced with the `oneside` option instead of `twoside`. Try that and get back to us.

Comment: @Jubobs I tried the `oneside` option but I still am getting the same error. I did get it to approve my book with the following settings `\geometry{
    paperheight=8.00in,
    top=.75in,
    bottom=.75in, 
    paperwidth=5.25in,
    inner=.38in,
    outer=.75in,
    bindingoffset=.75in,
}` but when I received my proof, the text was very close to gutter and therefore, the text is very far away from the edges of the page.

Comment: @gekkostate: Updated my answer, maybe this (completely new) approach works for you.

Answer (score 2):

After several comments the problem seems to be rather on the side of createspace. There is a package available on github, that was made for creating books with LaTeX for publishing on createspace. Hopefully this helps:
https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/blob/master/createspace.sty

Reading the package contents is seems like

```
\usepackage[size=pocket]{createspace}
```

is better than all the `geometry`-stuff. Page size will be calculated automatically. In addition you might also want to play with the additional options `trim` and `bleed`.

---

**Making the borders visible**

Add `showframe` when you are loading the package `geometry`, then you can see for yourself:

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
```

This picture shows your settings on a A4-page:
[image]

As you can see, the marginpar is leaking outside of your original dimensions, to remove it, add `marginpar=0cm` in your `geometry`-settings.

Comment: I have updated the post with your answer but it makes no difference.

Comment: @gekkostate: Answer updated

Comment: I am familiar with this createspace package and as a matter of fact have used it but there is a bug in the package that I found and contacted the author about it. Due to this, I changed to geometry. I posted a comment regarding the setting I used to get approved before. Is it possible to manipulate that in some way so that the page is not so close to the gutter? **EDIT**: I have updated the post to contain an image of the other dimensions that I posted.

Comment: I have third update. It seems that only a portion of the book is out of line, namely the `Introduction`. This doesn't make much sense because the content before and the content after is perfectly formatted.

Comment: Ok, do *they* say that the Introduction is out of margin or did you checked if it leaks outside the displayed (remember the `showframe` feature) margins?

Comment: _They_ and I and marginpar indicate that the text is out of the showframe. This is a little weird. If I just use `showframe` separately from `geometry` then the text leaks but if I do `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` then it isn't leaking out.

Comment: Ok...try printing a page from the introduction and form elsewhere. Keep the scaling, so that it won't be enlarged by the printer. Then put both pages together and hold them against the light to be sure that the frame shown by `showframe` is not changed throughout the introduction.

Comment: Okay, I will do that and get back to you.

Comment: Did you had any success?

Comment: I just tried what you ask and the margins are perfectly fine on paper. The margin on the introduction and the margin in another chapter are the same. This is really confusing me.

Comment: Hmmm...then I an confused whether I got your second to last comment correctly? If you use `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` everything is fine? - meaning: text isn't leaking out and margins frame is always the same? So they would accept your book with `showframe` enabled? (Surely nobody would want that) And if you don't use it or call the `showframe` afterwards, then the text is leaking out and they won't accept it?...

Comment: I changed the settings just a little bit but the problem still persists. Now the introduction is fine and everywhere else the margins are off even though I printed it and the margins are correct according to `[showframe]`

Comment: What do you mean by "everywhere else the margins are off even though [...] the margins are correct according to `[showframe]`"?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. According to `[showframe]` it is correct and also when I printed it but when I put it up for the review, the interior reviewer says that is isn't the case.

Comment: Hmm...this confuses me, you may have to contact createspace again. Sorry for that :-(

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using the page layout stuff built into `memoir`. The class option `largecrownvopaper` corresponds to your dimensions of 8in x 5.25in, so from there you just need to make sure the margins are correct. This looks pretty close.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright,largecrownvopaper]{memoir}

\setulmarginsandblock{2.38cm}{2.38cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.29cm}{1.52cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

You can also check the dimensions with the `layout` package.

Comment: My dimensions are actually reversed, they are 5.25in x 8in. Is there are option for that or is that what you meant?

Comment: I meant the height is 8in and the width is 5.25in.